# TextToSpeech won't speak German "pro Minute"

Tags: android, text-to-speech

I've noticed that text-to-speech on Android skips the term "pro Minute" in German.

It works fine in English or when I adjust the term slightly, e.g. "pro Minnute" (note the duplicated 'n'). I've tried this with different applications, to make sure that this is not a programming error on my part.

Any explanations for this? Is there a list of 'keywords' that I should be aware of?

Android 5.1.1 - Cyanogen 12.1

Update: Still the same on Android 6.0.1

Comment: What if you try with `"pro min."`?

Comment: Thanks, "pro min." speaks fine. I'm using "in der Minute" now as a workaround - this has the same meaning. I'm still curios on why the original term has a special meaning.

Comment: Keine Ahnung... ;)